# How to write a QUERY where the Column values in the "Select" section are dependent on the value of another cell within that dataset

Tags: google-sheets-query

Collecting responses from a Google Form, I have two categories for the name of the person responding and the title of the play they are to assess. In one category, "Board Members" have a dropdown list of their names and the titles of plays available for them to evaluate, whereas the second category is for "Guest Readers" to choose their name from a dropdown list and the more limited play titles for them to choose from. I have the form working fine, but the results in the Google Sheet are as shown on the tab "Form Responses 3" tab of this example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9AK-Df-rgnNDKfeXRo0msoUHmVCIxs0EFD_HPDxWA4/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to build a QUERY statement that produces the outcome on the "Assessments" tab of the same sheet.

My thinking thus far is that the values of the Columns to choose from in the "Select " section of the QUERY are dependent on an embedded IF statement something like:

```
=query('Form Responses 3'!$A$2:$G, "Select '" & if('Form Responses 3'!$C2<>'',"D, C, G Where not E <>''", "F, E, G Where not C <>''") &"'")
```

I'm not sure of many things here -- I am confident I am getting lost in the ' and " frames -- but most specifically, can I even make the dynamic callback to a cell within the dataset in the IF formula that will manifest in each row of the QUERY result? Am I making any sense at all?

Comment: I can get the desired results in two individual sheets (one for each category), but I need the results to be combined into one sheet for further analysis.

Comment: This updated formula generates three entries but leaves out the play title and reader for the "Guest #1" entry:

`=query('Form Responses 3'!$A2:$G, "Select " &if('Form Responses 3'!$C2 <> "","D, C, G", "F, E, G"))`

Can anyone help with this?